# How to suspend node.js process on SIGTSTOP

Tags: node.js, keypress, suspend

I'm buidling a small tool in `node.js` that needs to listen to keypresses to execute some functionality.

To this end I'm using the [`keypress`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/keypress) library. I know how to 
set up key listeners and listen for the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key combination to quit the process (using `process.exit()`):

```
import keypress from 'keypress';
const stdin = process.stdin;
keypress(process.stdin);
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

process.stdin.on('keypress', function(ch, key) {
  if ( key && key.ctrl ) 
    if ( key.name == 'c') {
      console.log('quitting...');
      process.exit();
    } else {
      console.log('suspending...');
      // WHAT TO DO?
    }
  } else if ( ch ) {
    my_functionality(ch);
  }
});
```

I'm also listening for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the process,
but I do not know what code to execute to put the process in suspension.

I see two possible solutions, but I do not know how to implement any of them:

- listen to 'normal' keypresses only and let node process special ones 
  like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, so 
  it can just do its default behaviour.
- know what code to execute to emulate the suspension behaviour that is
  default when node receives `SIGSTOP`.

Answer (score 2):

You want...

```
process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGSTOP');
```